# Ruby/Rails: Natural increase of string (succ)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, increment

I would like to have consecutive invoice numbers, but the `succ` method sucks (pun intended) in this case.

```
'427'.succ
> '428' (works!)

'2021-9'.succ
> '2022-0' (does not work)

'2021.9'.succ
> '2022.0' (does not work)
```

I couldn't find a gem for this, only a gem to sort strings naturally. If no one knows any existing solutions, I will answer this question with a self-programmed method shortly.

Comment: Separate both parts, increment the right-hand side and re-join them afterwards, e.g. `a, b = str.split('-')` followed by `[a, b.succ].join('-')`. A cleaner approach would be to store the current year and its consecutive number separately and build the invoice number out of the two parts as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `String#gsub` and apply `succ` on the matched digit:

```
'427'.gsub(/\D(\d+)$|^\d+$/, &:succ)
# "428"
'2021-9'.gsub(/\D(\d+)$|^\d+$/, &:succ)
# "2021-10"
'2021-624'.gsub(/\D(\d+)$|^\d+$/, &:succ)
# "2021-625"
```

Comment: Thank you, it will be difficult to generate invoice numbers like "2021-625" from that.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I thought you wanted to increase on based on days. You can see the updated answer @Railsana

Comment: ```gsub(/\D(\d+)$/, &:succ)``` works great, but it doesn't increase a version without any dividers. "427" remains "428".

Comment: You can probably use a condition there. If the string contains a divider, then you can use gsub plus succ, otherwise just succ.

Comment: Thank you. I think I have I cannot avoid a condition since the current answer returns "2022-10" (it increases both the 2021 and the 9).

Comment: You could add begin/end of string delimiters `^\d+$`.

Comment: ```.gsub(/\D(\d+)$|^\d+$/, &:succ)```seems to work perfectly. Please edit your answer, so I can mark it as the solution. Thank you very much!